# ¿Cómo usar dos submit en formulario con php?

Tags: php, html, jquery

estoy desarrollando un formulario de registro la cual tiene dos botones, el primero tiene la función de imprimir (envía los datos a otro form con fpdf, llena los datos en un pdf) y el otro tiene que guardar la información en la tabla de mi bd y quisiera saber la forma de usar dos submit.
Este es mi código html:

```
<form method="POST" target="_blank" action="http://localhost/mesadepartes/new">
        <textarea class="form-control z-depth-1 descripExp" id="exampleFormControlTextarea6" rows="3" placeholder="Escribe Aquí..." name="txaDesQ"></textarea>
        <textarea class="form-control z-depth-1" id="exampleFormControlTextarea6" rows="3" placeholder="Escribe Aquí..." name="txaPruebasIn"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" name="btnImprimir" class="btn btn-warning">IMPRIMIR Y FIRMAR</button>
        <button type="submit" name="envExpediente" class="btn btn-primary" style="border-color: #666;">ENVIAR EXPEDIENTE </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Puedes usar el atributo formaction de la etiqueta button https://stackoverflow.com/a/31919153/2553194

Comment: Thanks, me funciono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al tener un name distinto, puedes hacer una cosa distinta con cada uno, mirando el array $_REQUEST.

En este caso al pulsar el botón ENVIAR EXPEDIENTE  en la página php de destino, existira la variable $_REQUEST["envExpediente"] almacenando el valor: ENVIAR EXPEDIENTE

Si por el contrario se pulsa IMPRIMIR Y FIRMAR, en la página php de destino, existira la variable $_REQUEST["btnImprimir"] que almacenará el valor: IMPRIMIR Y FIRMAR

Comprobando cual de las dos variables existe al llegar a la página php de destino, con `isset(variable)` puedes hacer una cosa u otra

**NOTA:** Esto sé que funciona con
`<input type="submit" ...>` por un pequeño desarollo que hice para una compañía donde se daba el mismo caso. No estoy seguro de si esto funcionará tal cual con `<button ... >` pero debería funcionar igual.